# In ReactiveUI is it possible to with WhenAnyValue to get base class dependency properties

Tags: c#, xaml, system.reactive, reactiveui

I may be doing this wrong (TM), but I have a data object that is derived off a interface, then a base class which implements the interface as dependency properties.

When using WhenAnyValue it goes off and checks for the field:

```
type.GetRuntimeFields().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == propertyName + "Property" && x.IsStatic);
```

The problem of course is that "GetRuntimeFields" don't understand about the static fields through the reflection as by default unless you are using the BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy flag it won't find it (which GetRuntimeFields won't do)

Is there a way to specify the DependencyProperty directly for WhenAnyValue?

I am using ReactiveUI 5.5.0.0

Thanks,
Glenn

I came up with a solution that worked for me, that is to create my own ICreatesObservableForProperty and registering it in my application constructor with the RxApp. This allowed me the flexible of what I wanted to do.

Comment: Why are you using dependency properties at all? These shouldn't be in your viewmodel. They have a place in your UI in controls, but I wouldn't pollute your viewmodels with them - life is easier if you keep WPF constructs in the view as far as possible.

Comment: Mainly due to large number of items that need to be binded to, and performance is critical. Reflection is a big bottle neck in this situation. We have a trade-off in this case of Performance vs isolation of model. We are happy to have the trade off with Reactive UI calling reflection to get the dependency property binding that is a one time startup cost.

Comment: Interesting. What number of items of we talking about (where it starts to matter)?

Comment: Potentially many of hundreds of thousands (large scale game editor). It's more the fact we need to give the milliseconds back to the game engine. But yeah I can understand your reservations about having DP in the view model.

Comment: Can you paste an example of this ViewModel, or in general get me a repro case?

Comment: The repro case would be something like 

    interface IMyViewModel<br>
    {
       int MyValue { get; }
    }

    public abstract class MyViewModelDepObjBase : IMyViewModel
    {
       ... Dependency Property to MyValue
    }

    public ConcreteViewModel : MyViewModelDepObjBase 
    {
       `public ConcreteViewModel()`
       `{`
          `this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.MyValue).Subscribe(...);`
       `}`
    `}`

Comment: Also, is MyViewModelDepObjBase a DependencyObject?

Comment: Yeah that would be. This issue would happen with derived controls with inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We figured out that this is a bug introduced in ReactiveUI 5.5, that is now fixed as of today :) Upgrade to 5.5.1 and this should go away.